# System.IO.FileCopy sometimes throws "Not enough storage is available to process this command" error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.5, system.io.file

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that performs a copy of a docx file using System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName).

where:

- sourceFileName : C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyASPNetMVCApp\Data\Documents\Template
- destFileName   : C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyASPNetMVCApp\Documents\Temp

For some reason I do not know it is throwing below error in the event log entry of my application (I have a try-catch to log error to event log in case of error):

> Not enough storage is available to process this command

I have checked that disk has enough disk space available and even application pool identity has the correct permissions to read/write from/to these folders. So what's the problem?

Comment: Maybe related: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this/9624b57d-ea4c-41fa-aae0-b52e99b69fab

Comment: @KlausGütter There is no other alternative to do it without touching the registry? My files are about 5MB only.